# Is there a solution to store user's data in a cassandra table with distinct non primary values only?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

Trying to design a cassandra database table to store user's profile information - username, Name, Mobile Number and Email ID. username is used as the clustering key, whereas I want to limit Mobile Number or Email ID used by one user should not be used by another user.

Is there any option to limit each column for distinct values or any workaround?

Trying to design a schema with two distinct non primary values. Cassandra is not offering DISTINCT on primary keys only.

Answer (score 0):

You are expressing 2 different queries, it will be 2 different tables.
(as it is 99% the case with Cassandra).

You will have to create a dedicated table to look up for the mobile. In the lookup table you can have the email as clustering key to also validate couples.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_profile_by_email(
  email    TEXT,
  mobile   TEXT,
  username TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY((email))
);

CREATE TABLE users_profile_check_mobile(
  mobile TEXT,
  email  TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY((mobile), email)
);
```

Inserting 2 users (sample of good usage of a batch statement)

```sql
BEGIN BATCH
INSERT INTO users_profile_by_email(email, mobile, username) VALUES ('user1@foo.com', '111-111-1111', 'user1');
INSERT INTO users_profile_check_mobile(mobile, email) VALUES ('111-111-1111', 'user1@foo.com');
APPLY BATCH;

BEGIN BATCH
INSERT INTO users_profile_by_email(email, mobile, username) VALUES ('user2@foo.com', '222-222-2222', 'user2');
INSERT INTO users_profile_check_mobile(mobile, email) VALUES ('222-222-2222', 'user2@foo.com');
APPLY BATCH;
```

A user is registrating...does:

*Is the email already in use?*

```
select count(email) as email_count
from users_profile_by_email 
where email='user1@foo.com'
```

*Is the mobile already in used ?*

```sql
select count(mobile) as mobile_count
from users_profile_check_mobile 
where mobile='222-222-2222';
```

*Is the couple `email/mobile` valid?*

```sql
select count(*) as mobile_count
from users_profile_check_mobile 
where mobile='222-222-2222' 
and email='user1@foo.com';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The solution is perfect until the existence check of the specific email or mobile. Whereas the two parallel insertions after two parallel checks may perform an overwrite as Cassandra upserts always.

Even though the time between READ and WRITE is small. it cannot be discarded.

Comment: ok for the insertions into the users_profile_check_mobile you want to add IF NOT EXISTS in the batch. eg: INSERT INTO users_profile_check_mobile(mobile, email) VALUES ('222-222-2222', 'user2@foo.com') IF NOT EXISTS;) In a batch you have a single LWT it works.